# How do i know on whic class of many am i hovering, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

For example i have html like this:

```
<div class='item'></div>
<div class='item'></div>
<div class='item'></div>
<div class='item'></div>
...
```

Now with javascript how do i know whic class i am hovering on, or how do i get the class im hovering on.
I know they are being displayed as an array in javascript and i was always using:

```
var myElement = document.getElementsByClassName['class'][0/1/2];
```

So my needs would be something like this:

```
myElement.onmouseover = function () {//code}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const getClass = (ev) => {                       // ev is the mouseenter Event
  const cls = ev.target.className                // ev.target is the mouseentered Elem.
  console.log( cls );
};

const item = document.querySelectorAll(".item"); // Get all your .item Elements

[...item].forEach( el => {                       // Every one of them...
  el.addEventListener("mouseenter", getClass);   // Assign a mouseenter Event callback
});
```

```html
<div class='item i1'>HOVER ME</div>
<div class='item i1'>HOVER ME</div>
<div class='item i2'>HOVER ME</div>
<div class='item i2'>HOVER ME</div>
```

Read also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Comparison_of_Event_Targets

Comment: Can't you just do `document.querySelectorAll(".item").addEventListener(...)`?

Comment: @MichelTomas JS is not jQuery :) `addEventListener` operates over a single item, not over a collection.

Comment: you're damn right, React is making me forget how vanilla JS events actually work. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `e.target` or `e.currentTarget`

```
document.querySelector('.item').forEach(function (item) {
    item.onmouseover = function (e) {
        // If you want myElement
        console.log(e.currentTarget.className)
        // If you want the element onto which the event occurred
        console.log(e.target.className)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? At least it deserves some explanation, as this definitely answers "Now with javascript how do i know whic class i am hovering on".

Answer (score -1):

This should work.

```js
const items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
for(let i=0; i < items.length; i++){
  items[i].addEventListener('mouseover', (e)=> {
    console.log(e.target.className);
  })
}
```

```css
.item {
border:1px solid black;
width: 100px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='item red'>Red</div>
<div class='item yellow'>Yellow</div>
<div class='item blue'>Blue</div>
<div class='item green'>Green</div>
```